# Basic for loop explanation needed

Tags: java, increment

```
for (int i =0; i<5;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        System.out.print(i*j%5);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I understand the output for this Java program will look like this:

```
00000
01234
02413
03142
04321
```

but what I don't understand is how the function (i*j%5) can return any number at all since j will always be less than five, so shouldn't all j%5 = 0 therefore making i * 0=0 ?

update:
ok so now i know

```
3%5 = 3
2%5= 2
4%5 = 4
```

according to java. I originally assumed that since 5 does not go into 3 at all (3%5 for example) then the modulo would be 0. But I was wrong then, java must read it as just the original number? also thank you to everyone who responded so quickly <3

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: `j%5` will only be `0` when `j` is an even multiple of `5`.

Comment: @CryptoFool do you mean when `j` is a multiple of `5`? "An even multiple" I would interpret as 10, 20, 30, etc because it's 2x, 4x, 6x, etc `5`. But really, `j%5 == 0` anytime `j` is any multiple of `5` (5, 10, 15, 20, etc)

Comment: Please read the link @RobbyCornelissen suggested.

Comment: I think you're confusing the division (`/`) and modulus (`%`) operators. For `j` between 0 and 5 `j/5==0` but `j%5 == j`.

Comment: By "even multiple" I just meant "integer multiple".  So what you said in your last comment is what I was saying as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse the modulo operator with the division operator: `j%5` is the same as `j` if `j` is from 0 to 4.

**But**, since multiplication operator and modulo operator have [the same precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17), the expression `i*j%5` grouped from left to right, i.e. it is evaluated as `(i * j) % 5` and not, as you seem to assume, as `i * (j % 5)`.

Answer (score -1):

as per the order of precedence, the multiplication will take place before the division, so that's why you will not get zero.

Comment: The '%' operator is modulus, not division.